# Attributes for TransformerFactory

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxp, transformer-model

where can I find the supported attributes I can set to Java's 7- javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory?
TransformerFactory.newInstance().**setAttribute**(**name**, value)

I'm referring to Java's own's JAXP (coming out-of-the-box), and NOT external implementation.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29 lists

> All implementations that implement JAXP 1.5 or newer are required to
>   support the XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and
>   XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET properties.
>
> ```
> Access to external DTDs in the source file is restricted to the protocols specified by the XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD property.
> ```
>
> If access is denied during transformation due to the restriction of
>   this property, TransformerException will be thrown by
>   Transformer.transform(Source, Result).
>
> ```
> Access to external DTDs in the stylesheet is restricted to the protocols specified by the XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD property.
> ```
>
> If access is denied during the creation of a new transformer due to
>   the restriction of this property, TransformerConfigurationException
>   will be thrown by the newTransformer(Source) method.
>
> ```
> Access to external reference set by the stylesheet processing instruction, Import and Include element is restricted to the protocols
> ```
>
> specified by the XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET property. If
>   access is denied during the creation of a new transformer due to the
>   restriction of this property, TransformerConfigurationException will
>   be thrown by the newTransformer(Source) method.
>
> ```
> Access to external document through XSLT document function is restricted to the protocols specified by the property. If access is
> ```
>
> denied during the transformation due to the restriction of this
>   property, TransformerException will be thrown by the
>   Transformer.transform(Source, Result) method.

Comment: Hi,
This documentation refer to properties, but not to the attributes.
They are set by .setProperty(..), but .setAttribute(...) is dealing with the attributes. For example, 
I've found in this site the attribute : "indent-number", which is not listed in 
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to have the Javadoc here

Comment: Where is the answer to the question @Martin Honnen?

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj, not sure what you want from me, if you think you have an answer other than reading the API docs or the source then provide it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I don't find a _list_ of attributes that can be used with TransformerFactory either in your answer or in the link you have provided. As the OP has commented, "This documentation refer to properties, but not to the attributes."

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj, still not sure what is the point of your comment to me in an attempt to a answer a question that is now more than four years old, the poster asked about `setAttribute` in Java 7 and I pointed to and cited from the official documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29. If that one is wrong then complain to Oracle. If you want to provide an answer of your own then post one. But don't bug me as if I were supposed to provide "the answer".

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I just wanted to let know the reason for downvoting your answer - which is, it didn't answer the question.